# GWT How to Modify default project sample code?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

When we create a new GWT project using the Eclipse plugin, it gives an option to generate sample source code for the project as shown below: 
[image: Option to generate source code]

Selecting the above option, generates sample code structure that looks something like this:

```
    MyTestProject
   src/
        com/
          mytestproject/
            MyTestProject.gwt.xml        
            client/
              GreetingService.java
              GreetingServiceAsync.java
              MyTestProject.java      
            server/
              GreetingServiceImpl.java   war/  
        MyTestProject.css
        MyTestProject.html
        WEB-INF/
          web.xml
          classes/
          lib/
           ...GWT JARs...
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to modify/customize this default code to automatically generate a few more classes to jump start my projects. Any suggestions to get me started in the right direction will be appreciated. For example how do I find the source from where this code is getting generated or more popular approach to create such templates for kick-starting a new project.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own sample/template project with as many classes as you need, add it to a git/mercurial repository, and import from this repository every time you start a new project.

Comment: Thanks for your response Andrei. Could you elaborate a bit more. Although I am aware of code repositories, I have never used one. Is there some good  starting point for understanding this process of working with stored code? Also, how would it be different from baselining an existing GWT project in Eclipse and keep cloning it compared to using an online code repository?

Comment: You can clone Eclipse projects, of course, but as a rule you should never have a project which is not in a repository, unless it's for training/learning purposes. So it's very important to learn how to use code repositories. Github and Bitbucket are two popular choices.

Comment: Have been struggling to create a new GWT project from an existing project. It is too much of work to do it manually. Tried copy pasting the packages to the new project but that created a new package in the project. There is definitely something very basic that I am missing. It can't be that complex.